# Opentelemetry Autoconfiguration

Tags: java, spring-boot, open-telemetry

Having issues with `AutoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdk` in the example below I'm trying to:

- Initialize a Bean that can be used to send metrics through.
- Configure the OTEL server from the System variables as follows:

```
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT https://*******/api/v2/otlp
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_HEADERS  Authorization=XXXX
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_METRICS_TEMPORALITY_PREFERENCE   delta
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_PROTOCOL http/protobuf
OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES    "service.name=java-quickstart,service.version=1.0.1"
OTEL_SERVICE_NAME   service-name
```

- Add additional configuration from my Runtime.

```
@Configuration
public class OpenTelemetryConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public Resource resource() {
    return Resource.getDefault()
        .merge(
            Resource.create(
                Attributes.of(
                    ResourceAttributes.SERVICE_INSTANCE_ID,
                    RandomStringUtils.random(12, true, true))))
        .merge(
            Resource.create(
                Attributes.of(
                    ResourceAttributes.SERVICE_VERSION,
                    Optional.ofNullable(System.getProperty("VERSION")).orElse("N/A"))));
  }

  @Bean
  public OpenTelemetry getOpenTelemetrySdk(Resource resource) {
    return AutoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdk.builder().setResultAsGlobal()
        .addMeterProviderCustomizer(
            (sdkMeterProviderBuilder, configProperties) ->
                sdkMeterProviderBuilder.addResource(resource))
        .build()
        .getOpenTelemetrySdk();
  }
}
```

Problem is that the service name is not getting propagated correctly and it seems SERVICE_INSTANCE_ID and SERVICE_VERSION isn't either.

Any clues as to how to combine runtime and env variables configuration together properly?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution:

```
  @Bean
  public Resource getResource(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    return Resource.getDefault()
        .merge(
            Resource.create(
                Attributes.of(
                    ResourceAttributes.SERVICE_INSTANCE_ID,
                    RandomStringUtils.random(12, true, true))))
        .merge(
            Resource.create(
                    Attributes.of(
                        ResourceAttributes.SERVICE_VERSION,
                        Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv(VERSION)).orElse(NA)))
                .merge(
                    Resource.create(
                        Attributes.of(
                            ResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME,
                            Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv(OTEL_SERVICE_NAME))
                                .orElse(
                                    Optional.ofNullable(
                                            StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(
                                                applicationContext.getApplicationName(), null))
                                        .orElse(NA))))));
  }



  @Bean
  public OpenTelemetry getOpenTelemetrySdk(Resource resource) {
    log.info("OpenTelemetry SDK initialized with OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT");
    return AutoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdk.builder()
        .addMeterProviderCustomizer(
            (sdkMeterProviderBuilder, configProperties) ->
                sdkMeterProviderBuilder.addResource(resource))
        .build()
        .getOpenTelemetrySdk();
  }
```